# Auto cascade update of values in Table

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time, insert

Is it possible to auto update a row in tableA when tableB is updated?

For example:

```
Create TableA
(
  examno number not null,
  hourscompleted,
  Constraint examno number_PK PRIMARY KEY(examno number)
  CONSTRAINT hourscompleted_FK FOREIGN KEY (hourscompleted_FK) 
  REFERENCES tableB (endtime-  startime) 
  ON Update CASCADE
)

Create TableB
(
  Indexno not null
  starttime date,
  endtime date,
  Constraint INDEXNO_PK Primary Key (Indexno)
)
```

Secondly, could I reference it in this way tableB (endtime -  startime)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want Triggers.  You don't mention which database you are using but you tagged your question with `oracle`.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm) is some documentation about Coding Triggers in Oracle.  They should allow you to do what you are asking for.

I don't understand your second question.

Comment: my second question is would it be possible to create your foreign key and references it to (endtime-startime). I'm using oracle sql developer.

Comment: So something like a concatenated key based on the difference between endtime and starttime?  I'm not sure how you would do that.

Comment: yup. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You could possibly create a composite key using start and end time.  It wouldn't be the calculation of the difference though.  It would just be the combination of start and end times that would be used as the key.  (That is if Oracle will even allow dates as keys.  I'm not sure.)

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Composite_key

Comment: Not that but thanks. i'll try out the triggers and see if it works.